# Application not Working but after uninstall and install the same application works

Tags: android, linux-kernel, dalvik, android-build, android-install-apk

Hi friends i have strange issue in my application

First i  get a build(Version 1) and released that in to play store, but that build not installed in some devices, so i search with google for the issues and find that "Have to get build with recent adt"  so i get build and now it works in all device(Current version is 2 in play store ).

Now my problem is i have installed the version 1 in some device like sony experia  it says application not installed after that again i install the version 2 in same device it installed when i open it  force closed and my log cat says

```
sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
```

But if delete the version 2 and again install the same version its open and works correctly.

I can't say to my customer to delete the current app and install the same again, So i need fix it if any small hint also can help me i eagerly waiting for your replay.

Note: I am assume that the problem is not with the code. The problem is with the build version 1, It may partially installed in a device and its not cleared from the device while installing new Version 2.

Comment: R u also updating versionCode in manifest file

Comment: @GiruBhai Yes that's i have done.

Comment: Are you doing database changes from version 1 to 2?if so then upgrade your database version also

Answer (score 0):

I think you have just to upgrade your database version.

Comment: Yes i have done that , Actually the problem is application cant able to write anything to the database folder. My assumption is Version 1 partially installed and that not cleared while installing the version 2  so version 2 cannot access the database folder.